# Python 2.7.10: No output when I run

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to run the following program:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")

brad = turtle.Turtle()
#count=0
# while(count<4):
brad.forward(100)
brad.right(90)
#    count = count + 1
wait_for_user()    
window.exitonclick()
brad.done()

draw_square
```

But when I run it, nothing happens. I don't see any output as such. I get blank message in console too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function like `draw_square`, anything you make inside of that function stays inside of it.  In this case, you say

```
def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
```

That's fine, but outside of the function, there is no such thing as `window`.  So you should then get an error when you try `window.bgcolor("red")`.

You have two choices: (1) delete that function line and unindent the definition of `window`; (2) indent everything after the definition, so that it is also inside the function, then call the function with `draw_square()` after you've defined it.

Another problem: `wait_for_user()` is not defined.  Is this a method of `brad`, or `window`, or a function inside `turtle`?

This works for me:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

Comment: yeah that works..sorry i am new to python so some learning curve